# Spark sql read json file from hdfs failed

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hivecontext

My code like this:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val customers = sqlContext.read.json("jsonfilepath")
```

In spark-shell occur error ,I can not understand this:

```
17/06/19 09:59:04 ERROR bonecp.PoolWatchThread: Error in trying to obtain a connection. Retrying in 7000ms
java.sql.SQLException: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.setReadOnly(Unknown Source)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.setReadOnly(ConnectionHandle.java:1324)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.<init>(ConnectionHandle.java:262)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.fillConnections(PoolWatchThread.java:115)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.run(PoolWatchThread.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ERROR 25505: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericAuthorizer.setReadOnlyConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.setReadOnly(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

How can I solve it?Thanks

Comment: error message clearly says that you need to change permissions of your database

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `HiveContext` to read json data?

Use `SOLContext` instead.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val customers = sqlContext.read.json("jsonfilepath")
```

Comment: I want to save data to hive use HiveContext,SQLContext works for me